# How to get scroll width from web browser control in wpf/windows c#

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I am using web browser control in wpf c#.
I have render html in web browser control which width have more than windows width.
then It's displaying scroll bar.
so I need scroll width,or width of html body.
if any one have solution please help me.
The control can be windows web browser control or WPF web browser control.

Comment: Maybe this link helps you: http://www.wenda.io/questions/930300/getting-the-scroll-value-from-a-webbrowser-control-c-sharp.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ScrollRectangle will get the dimensions of the scrollable region

```
IEWb.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height;
IEWb.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width;
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the width

Comment: thanks Ali, I am getting height width but I am using html string  not file system to render in webbrowser control.I have inject this css in body.      style="-webkit-column-width:800px;  margin-right:800px; -moz-column-width: 800px; column-width: 800px; -webkit-column-gap: 0px; -moz-column-gap: 0px; column-gap: 0px; -webkit-column-rule: 0px solid #000;-moz-column-rule: 0px solid #000;column-rule: 0px solid #000; height:800px; overflow:visible !important; position:absolute; margin:0px; -moz-margin:0px;-webkit-margin:0px;display:block;".